# Is it differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let us consider the function

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2\sin {\dfrac{\pi}{x}} & x \neq 0\\
0                        & x=0
\end{cases}
$$

We want to check its differentiability at $x=0$.

By the definition of $f'(x)$, the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ would be $$f'(0)=\displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{h^2\sin {\dfrac{\pi}{h}}}{h}$$ which would be $$f'(0)=\displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} h\sin \frac{\pi}{h}$$

Using the squeeze theorem, we can prove that this limit is equal to $0$.

So according to the above procedure, the function is differentiable at $x=0$.

But, when we look at the graph of this function, it doesn't seem differentiable (below)
[image: Graph]

In addition to this, when we find $f'(x)$ by using the $u.v$ rule and the chain rule, $f'(x)$ does not exist.

So, is it differentiable or not?

Comment: So it's differentiable! and $f'(0)=0$ i.e. it has a horizontal tangent line on $0$.

Comment: Seems differentiable to me.

Comment: You're deceived by the fact that $f$ is not twice differentiable at $0$. Graphs are useful, but they can be misleading.

Comment: This is the classical example of a function differentiable but not $C^1$ (the limit of $f'$ in $0$ does not exist).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't check if a function is differentiable at $x=a$ if the function is not defined at $a$. In general, a function $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if $f^\prime(a)$ exists for $a\in\operatorname{domain}f$. If you define $f(0)$ in this case to be $0$ then your function is indeed differentiable at $x=0$ by what we said above.

**Edit:** You claimed that using the product rule and the chain rule means that $f^\prime(x)$ doesn't exist. Well let's check: $$\eqalign{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\,x^2\sin\left(\tfrac \pi x\right)\right]&=x^2\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos\left(\tfrac\pi x\right)+\sin\left(\tfrac\pi x\right)\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^2\\&=x^2\left(-\dfrac{\pi\cos\left(\tfrac\pi x\right)}{x^2}\right) +\sin\left(\tfrac\pi x\right)\cdot2x\\&=2x\sin\left(\tfrac\pi x\right)-\pi\cos\left(\tfrac\pi x\right).\\}$$
So $f^\prime(x)$ seems to not exist when $x=0$, but you have to keep in mind that since you have defined $f(0)$ to be $0$ then what you're really differentiating is the piecewise function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\left(\tfrac\pi x\right), & x\neq0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}.$$
And its derivative is: $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
2x\sin\left(\tfrac\pi x\right)-\pi\cos\left(\tfrac\pi x\right), & x\neq0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases},$$ which makes sense since $f$ is continuous: $x\mapsto x^2\sin\left(\tfrac\pi x\right)$ being defined everywhere given that $x\neq0$, so the remaining thing is to check that: $$\lim_{x\to0^-}x^2\sin\left(\tfrac\pi x\right)=0=\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2\sin\left(\tfrac\pi x\right).$$

Comment: It is usually
 implied (or explicitly stated) that the function is defined to be zero at zero.

Comment: @Brad Well the OP didn't explicitly state it, but if he define it that way then according to my answer the function is differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @Hakim But i do have one doubt--Do the left hand derivative and right hand derivative at $x=0$ match? That condition should be satisfied for $f$ to be differentiable, right?

Comment: @user157130 You mean the left hand limit and right hand limit as $x\to0$?

Comment: @Hakim No i mean [left and right hand derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_and_right_derivative)

Comment: @user157130 Ah, thought you were thinking of the limit as $x\to0^+$ and as $x\to0^-$. To answer on that matter you need to know that if a function is differentiable everywhere doesn't necessarily mean that its derivative will be continuous.

Comment: I just wanted to add a note to your note.

Comment: @Brad Thanks then. ;-)

Comment: Your result of differentiating the piecewise function looks suspicious. How could you differentiate the second case where $x=0$ if it's defined at a single point?

Comment: @Ruslan The function is continuous near that point, in fact the limit from the left is the same as the limit from the right. So the derivative does make sense. You can try it on Wolfram by the naive `Derivative Piecewise[{{(x^2)*sin[pi/x],0<x},{(x^2)*sin[pi/x],0>x}, {0,x=0}}]`. However, the second derivative of $f$ is indeterminate at $x=0$ since $f^\prime$ isn't continuous at $x=0$. Again you can check that through Wolfram `Derivative Piecewise[{{(2x)*(sin[pi/x])-pi*cos[pi/x],0<x},{(2x)*(sin[pi/x])-pi*cos[pi/x],0>x}, {0,x=0}}]`.

Answer (score 4):

First you must extend your function in $x=0$ by setting $f(0)=0$. Then your computation is correct, the function is differentiable in $0$. The graph also confirms this, since in $x=0$ the function is very close to the horizontal line.

**addendum**

You can use the chain rule and product rule when you compute the derivative of two differentiable functions. So you can safely use that rule when $x\neq 0$ and you find the correct derivative. For $x=0$, however, the function is not a product: it is a function defined by cases. When $x\neq 0$ you can restrict your function to $x\neq 0$ so that it becomes a product of differentiable functions. When $x=0$ you cannot. So your last resort is apply the very definition of limit.

Once that you have found the derivative in every point you can observe that the derivative in $x=0$ is not the limit of the derivative for $x\to 0$. In other words: this is (the most famous example of) a differentiable function whose derivative is not continuous.
The only possibility for this to happen is when the derivative $f'(x)$ has no limit when $x\to 0$, and this is exactly the case.

Comment: By the definition of a derivative, the function doesn't need to be defined. A tangent is a $\textbf{limiting}$ case of a chord.

Comment: To have a chord passing through $(0,f(0))$ you need to know what is $f(0)$.

Comment: @user157130 If you define $f(0)$ to be $0$, then the chord does pass through $(0,f(0))$.

Comment: @Hakim $f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f'(h)}{h}$. This clearly shows that the tangent doesn't pass $\textbf{through}$ the point $(0,f(0))$. There is a limit outside the expression.

Comment: @user157130 that's not the definition of derivative.

Comment: @user157130 Check my edit.